# Redirect page based on userlogin type

Tags: grails, groovy

Upon successful user login i want the page to redirect to `/person/personCreate` and it did work after adding the following code to `Config.groovy`.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/person/personCreate"
```

Now, i have two types of Users `SuperHuman` and `Human`. If the usertype is `SuperHuman` i want the page to be redirected `/person/superHumanPage` or else if the user type is `Human` i want the page to be redirected to `/person/personCreate`

How can i get this done ?

update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the spring security plugin, you'll find a LoginController.groovy.template and an auth.gsp.template.

You should copy those into your project and then modify the `def auth()` method to look something like this:

```
/**
 * Show the login page.
 */
def auth = {
    def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
        if (currentUser.userType.human)) {
            redirect controller: 'human'
        }
        else if (currentUser.userType.superHuman) {
            redirect controller: 'superHuman'
        }
        else {
            redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        }

        return
    }

    String view = 'auth'
    String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"
    render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                               rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
}
```

Comment: WH\hat do you mean by InstaceOf ? I have a field in the `user` model called userType and some of the users are `Human` and some are  `SuperHuman`. How can i get this done ?

Comment: `currentUser` returns the domain object so you can check whatever fields you want. In our application, we have different sub-types of users so my example used instanceOf() to differentiate (instead of a type field). I've edited to just check the userType instead.

Comment: I have updated my post when i copied the LoginController.groovy i get the above errors (See updated post above). I actually copy pasted the code from https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy#

Comment: Are you using version 2.0-RC4 of the plugin? If not, you need to copy the one from whatever version you are using. The link you provided is for the latest (possibly unreleased version).

Comment: I am using `2.0-RC2 `, but i am not able to find LoginController.groovy. I even googled for the source but its not available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're distinguishing between super humans and regular humans based on an attribute of the `User` class. As you're using spring security, a much more natural way to make this distinction is to define these as roles (AKA authorities) and assign them to each user as appropriate.

You can then implement your post-login redirection action like this:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class PersonController {

  def personCreate() {
    if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('SUPER_HUMAN')) {
      redirect action: 'superHumanHome'  
    } else {
      redirect action: 'humanHome'
    }
  }

  def superHumanHome() {
    // show the super human's home page
  }

  def humanHome() {
    // show the human's home page
  }
}
```

By the way, in your question, you said that `personCreate` is the action that should handle the redirection logic, and this is also that action that human's should be redirected to. This will create an infinite loop of redirection for human's, which is why I've redirected humans to a different action in the controller above.

Comment: This technically will require two redirects (not a huge deal). Typically, if you want to control more about the login process, overriding the LoginController is the built-in way to do it and works pretty well. I do agree with you that the human/superHuman thing is more of a role distinction than a type.

Comment: I am using `spring-security-core:2.0-RC2`. What is the import for `SpringSecurityUtils ` ?

Comment: I've added it to my post