# LoginController file not found in plugins

Tags: grails

Where can i find the source for `compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'`, I checked in the plugins but there's nothing like that.

I need to find the `LoginController.groovy` file. I am using Grails 2.2.4

I have attached a screenshot of the plugins folder.

[image]

Comment: If you've added the `spring-security-core` plugin dep to your BuildConfig but it's not showing up in Eclipse then you probably need to do a "refresh dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the spring security plugin is [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core). The `LoginController` class is [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy).

Comment: Yes this is for Grails 3.2.4. I am looking for grails 2.2.4

Comment: Huh? There's no such thing as Grails 3.2.4

Comment: I have tried copying the LoginController.groovy and it isn't working. Refer previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255549/redirect-page-based-on-userlogin-type/25255732?noredirect=1#comment39350172_25255732 I am stuck at this point. help.

Comment: @Illep I've answered your other question